# How to get only unsubscribed records from API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, deployment

Could you please any one help me on, How to get only unsubscribed records using list id from API?

I tried to use the code in this article: [Retrieving Subscribers Using ListID](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_subscribers_using_listid/), but I am unable to get just unsubscribed records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can request the unsubscribed contacts by listid via the SOAP-API using the following body for your envelope:

```
<s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
      <RetrieveRequest>
         <ObjectType>SubscriberList</ObjectType>
         <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
         <Properties>Status</Properties>
         <Filter xsi:type="ComplexFilterPart">
           <LeftOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
             <Property>List.ID</Property>
             <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
             <Value>[YOUR LIST ID HERE]</Value>
          </LeftOperand>
          <LogicalOperator>AND</LogicalOperator>
          <RightOperand xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
            <Property>Status</Property>
              <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
              <Value>Unsubscribed</Value> 
          </RightOperand>
        </Filter>
      </RetrieveRequest>
   </RetrieveRequestMsg>
</s:Body>
```